# Error "Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Llevo mucho tiempo lidiando con esta línea de código y no se porque da error:

```
private void metodo()
    {
        string cadena = dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    }
```

Simplemente quiero guardar el contenido de un datagrid en una variable tipo string, pero siempre me manda error de "Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto".

Intente hacer `"dataGridView2 = new DataGridView();"` antes de hacer la igualación pero aun así me dice que me asegure de que el valor no sea nulo o algo así.

¿Qué hago amigos?

Comment: Puede ser que cuando esta línea se ejecuta, el `dataGridView` aun no se haya creado. Al hacer el new DataGridView() solo estas creando una referencia, pero en ningún momento le has asignado valores a ninguna de sus posiciones, por lo tanto el valor que toma la posición es nula (no existe).

Comment: @David_helo Gracias por tu respuesta!! pero me explico mejor. Veras, ese dataGridView2 al que hago referencia ya existe, de hecho, está ya por defecto en el formulario. Yo lo que hago es abrir el formulario y  llenar ese mismo datagridview2, y ya con el datagridview lleno llamo a ese metodo de arriba.

Comment: @David_helo Gracias por tu respuesta!! pero me explico mejor. Veras, ese dataGridView2 al que hago referencia ya existe, de hecho, está ya por defecto en el formulario. Yo lo que hago es abrir el formulario y  llenar ese mismo datagridview2, y ya con el datagridview lleno llamo a ese metodo de arriba. no comprendo porque me dice que lo ponga como instancia.

Comment: me gustaria mejor hacer esto                                                      
                                                                                                     for (y = 0; y <= int.Parse(cad); y++)
            {
                WriTemp.WriteLine(this.dataGridView2.Rows[y].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            }                                                                                                                                  para hacerlo mas eficiente y no tener que llamar tantas veces al metodo, pero me sigue dando el mismo error si lo hago asi,

Comment: Estás seguro que al momento de llamar a tu método esa posición existe en tu tabla? Me parece que el error viene por ahí. Estas intentando acceder a una posición que no existe en ese momento por lo menos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este error es porque una de las componentes encadenadas es nula, comprueba con el debugger que `dataGridView2.Rows[0]` no sea nula, después `dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[1]` no sea nula, y por ultimo `dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value` no sea nulo antes de llamar a `ToString()`, o fallará al llamar a la siguiente

Comment: Ooooo muy cierto tenias razon, cuando llamaba al DGV aun no terminaba de llenar los campos, Gracias!!